# KML - hide name in label

Tags: xml, kml

I have tried very hard to give a Placemark a name yet not have it show up next to Placemark on the map. When you go to the left-hand side in Google Maps, all of the Placemarks in the list say `[no name]`. So, is there a way to get rid of the name (if I want to name the Placemarks and have that show up folder on the left)?

My KML structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2\">
<Document>
<name>foo</name>
<Folder>
    <name>bar</name>
    <description>foo bar</description>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ffff0000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <name></name>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>{},{},{},{},{},{}</coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon><href>file://{11}arrow.png </href></Icon>
                <heading>{4}</heading>
                <color>{10}</color>
                <scale>.6</scale>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <name></name>
        <scale>0</scale>
        <color>{10}</color>
        <description>{9}<br/><b>duration:</b> {8}<br/><b>time:</b> {7}<br/><b>CNR:</b> {5}<br/><b>BER:</b> {6}</description>
        <Point><coordinates>{0},{1},{2}</coordinates></Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ffff0000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <name></name>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>{},{},{},{},{},{}</coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon><href>file://{11}arrow.png </href></Icon>
                <heading>{4}</heading>
                <color>{10}</color>
                <scale>.6</scale>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <name></name>
        <scale>0</scale>
        <color>{10}</color>
        <description>{9}<br/><b>duration:</b> {8}<br/><b>time:</b> {7}<br/><b>CNR:</b> {5}<br/><b>BER:</b> {6}</description>
        <Point><coordinates>{0},{1},{2}</coordinates></Point>
    </Placemark>
    ...repeat <Placemark><LineString></LineString></Placemark><Placemark></Placemark>...
</Folder></Document>
</kml>
```

You can see that the name after the style block is empty because I really don't want it to show up next to the Placemark. (Quick note: the brackets are from a python script that writes to a file, so just ignore the brackets.)

If I do put something inside `<name</name>` (inside of the "normal" Placemark not inside the `LineString`) how do I make it not show up next to the Placemarks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `<LabelStyle>` element to set the `<scale>` property of the label to `0`.  This will allow you to have a name for the `Placemark` shown in the side panel but with no label displayed on the map.

Comment: I already tried that. No luck. I don't know if I put it in the right place. I just put it in the `<Style>` block after `<IconStyle>`, but it didn't work. At least I don't think it did. I can try it again, though.

Comment: Well, it worked. I think before I was also putting a <name> attribute inside of the <LabelStyle> but also taking it out of the Placemark.